# Issue in setting 'allowDeselction' property of ButtonBarButton component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, buttonbar

I would like to have tabs like individual buttons with some spacing between each button. It should function as normal tab navigator tabs.

So, I took a spark ButtonBar component and made changes to the ButtonBarSkin to look as I said above. The default behavior of the ButtonBar is Only one button in the ButtonBar control can be in the selected state. That means when you select a button in a ButtonBar control, the button stays in the selected state until you select a different button.

But, If I click on the already selected button, the selection goes off. I don't need such behavior. I want the button to be in the selected state even If I click it again as like in a tab bar control.

While I explored the buttonbarskin, I got to know that the buttonbarbutton is being used for defining the custom item renderer for buttonbar control. The ButtonBarButton component has a "**allowDeselection**"property which is by default true which means the selected button in the buttonbar can be deselected by clicking again. If set to false,the user must select a different button to deselect the currently selected button.

So, while declaring the buttonbarbutton component in the ButtonBarSkin, Im setting the **allowDeselection** property to false. Even then, the value is being set as true. While debugging the code, the thing I found weird is, the declared value i.e., **false** is set first and again it is being set as true for all the firstbutton, middlebutton and lastbutton of the buttonbar. I don't know how the property is getting set as true even I'm setting it to false while defining in buttonbarskin.

the code snippet is as follows :

### ButtonBar control

```
   <s:ButtonBar skinClass="skin.ButtonBarSkinCopy">
        <mx:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
        </mx:ArrayCollection>
    </s:ButtonBar>
```

### ButtonBarSkinCopy.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[ 
   /** 
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.ButtonBar")]
]]>
</fx:Metadata> 

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!--- 
        @copy spark.components.ButtonBar#firstButton
        @default spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin
        @see spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin
    -->
    <fx:Component id="firstButton">
        <s:ButtonBarButton allowDeselection="false" skinClass="skin.CustomButtonBarButtonSkin" />
    </fx:Component>

    <!--- 
        @copy spark.components.ButtonBar#middleButton
        @default spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarMiddleButtonSkin
        @see spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarMiddleButtonSkin
    -->
    <fx:Component id="middleButton" >
        <s:ButtonBarButton allowDeselection="false" skinClass="skin.CustomButtonBarButtonSkin" />
    </fx:Component>

    <!--- 
        @copy spark.components.ButtonBar#lastButton
        @default spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarLastButtonSkin
        @see spark.skins.spark.ButtonBarLastButtonSkin
    -->
    <fx:Component id="lastButton" >
        <s:ButtonBarButton allowDeselection="false" skinClass="skin.CustomButtonBarButtonSkin"/>
    </fx:Component>

</fx:Declarations>

<!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableDataContainer#dataGroup -->
<s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:ButtonBarHorizontalLayout gap="2"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

And CustomButtonBarButtonSkin.mxml is just a copy of ButtonBarButtonSkin. No change is done in the ButtonBarButtonSkin.mxml.

Kindly, Please share your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [requireSelection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#requireSelection) property of the `ButtonBar` component to `true`. When `requireSelection` is true, a button on the button bar cannot be de-selected. From the documentation:

> If true, a data item must always be selected in the control. If the value is true, the selectedIndex property is always set to a value between 0 and (dataProvider.length - 1).
>
> The default value is false for most subclasses, except TabBar. In that case, the default is true.
>
> The default value is false.

You can see it working in [this example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ButtonBar.html#includeExamplesSummary) (scroll down to see the demo).

Comment: Sunil! Thanks a lot. I tried for button bar component after seeing your answer. It works well. In the meanwhile, I started customizing the spark TabBar component and met the desired requirement. Thanks Once again!!! :)